# how do you find the median of 2 columns using R?

Tags: r, median

I am trying to compute the median vector of a data set `s` with column `A1` and `B1`. The median vector is the median for each  observation from both columns.

I tried to do this and it did not work.

```
median(s[c("A1","B1")])
```

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

The median of two observations is simply the mean. So `rowMeans(s[,c("A1","B1")])`. Equivalently, `apply(s[,c("A1","B1")],1,median)`

Comment: yes it works ! 

I was thinking of a doulbe loop already ,this is much simpler.



r = 0 

for (i in 1:2512)
{ 
  for (j in c(1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33))
  { result = median(s[i,j],s[i,j+4],s[i,j+8],s[i,j+12])
  r = rbind(r,result)

  
  }
}

Answer (score 7):

Another solution:

```
library(plyr)
colwise(median)(s[c("A1", "B1")])
```

which has the advantage of returning a data frame.

Comment: You need to install the plyr package, first.